# vector tiles map viewer for own data and with interaction

Tags: events, vector, dynamic, styles, tiles

there are same solutions for rendering vector tiles on client-side webbrowser. But i don't find one for my expectations.

I want to display a huge amount data (points, polygons) in a map viewer. I need vector data because of dynamic styling and interactions of the features. Its too much to load all in Google Maps and from my perspective its the right way to use vector tiles, because only nessesary and aggregated data for the viewpoint will be load.

So i dont need to style the basemap like i found thousands of examples. I only want to load my data as a vector tile layer on a raster (google satelite). But my features should by stylable, need to have normal events like clicking or mouseover and store properties. And last but not least it should be really fast ;-)

What viewer i need? And what is the workflow to create and serve the data as vector tiles?

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on a similar problem, strech - technologies are evolving, but mapbox-gl.js is one viewer you can use.  You might be able to use mapzen's system as well, but I haven't tried their system with large amounts of features, whereas I know mapbox does work better than leaflet and openlayers for your scenario.